# What is the best elimination method to use for a matrix when working with pen and paper?

Tags: matrices

In my fairly limited study of linear algebra, I came across a few algorithms (such as LU Decomposition) to optimize the calculation speed of an equation of the form Ax = b on a computer, but I am unsure as to which method to use when given this problem on pen and paper. Just from appearance, it doesn't seem like the LU Decomposition would be good for working by hand and it seems like there would be a better method than just Gaussian Jordan elimination.

Comment: depends on what you want from your solution. For really small systems it may be the case that matrix methods are not needed. The nice thing about Gauss Jordan or the related LU decomp is that you know when you're done.

Comment: Fastest method in my experience: pull out your phone and use the WolframAlpha app.  Unless it's $2\times 2$ or has a particularly nice form, matrix methods tend to be tediously long.  I still cringe at the thought of all those $4\times 4$ and $5\times 5$ matrices I had to row reduce by hand *without skipping any steps* for my Linear Algebra course. $^*$shudders$^*$

Comment: I understand that practically speaking, some sort of calculator should be used. That is the answer that I have found nearly everywhere. I just want to know what method I should be using when given an Ax = b equation on paper with no calculator option.